# Autocomplete the street name depending on current city

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geolocation

I am unable to find out a way that google.maps.places.Autocomplete only finds street names depending on the city of the user.

For example if a user opens the website from "Frankfurt" and starts to type any street name the Autocomplete should only search street name from frankfurt.

Comment: What have you tried? Where is your code? Did you read the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteOptions)?

Comment: I didn't find an places.Autocomplete on frankfurt.de

Answer (score 1):

You can set the radius or bounds for your autocomplete, you might figure out the radius or bounds based on a users' current or default location.

For more information, please refer to the [google.maps.places.AutocompletionRequest object specification](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompletionRequest) reference.